# Keyboard map in X version of Emacs not respecting system map

Tags: keyboard-layout

When I use emacs -nw in the terminal, it respects my keyboard map, but when I use the X version, I get a completely different map.  I would expect that my X keyboard mapping would be respected as it is in all my other Linux installations.

I'm at a loss as I've never encountered this problem before.  It's probably a simple reason, but the usual searches are bringing up nothing.  Is there a setting that I have overlooked that needs to be made?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Odd solution.  In Manjaro I'd inadvertently set the Japanese keyboard layout.  X emacs was respecting that setting, whereas the console version, and all other X apps were perhaps following locale.